# Centre of mass not recalculated after scaling

Tags: unity

I am spawning a prefab object at runtime (actually, in the `Start()` method of another object), and I need to apply a scaling to the object. I made a little component to handle this:

```
public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour {

  public Transform SpawnPrefab;
  public Vector3 Scale;

    void Start () {
      var spawn = Instantiate(SpawnPrefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
      spawn.localScale = Vector3.Scale(spawn.localScale, Scale);
      // spawn.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().ResetCenterOfMass();  // Has no effect
    }
}
```

The pivot point of the prefab I am spawning does not coincide with the centre of mass of the object. Therefore, the rescaling means that the centre of mass location relative to the pivot will change. However, it's *not* being updated automatically, so my spawned object has unexpected physics.

I tried adding a call to `GetComponent<Rigidbody>().ResetCenterOfMass()` immediately after the call to `Scale()`  (the commented-out line above), but this has no effect.

However, if I put the call to `ResetCenterOfMass()` in the `Start()` method of a separate little component added to the spawned object, e.g.

```
public class COMReset : MonoBehaviour {
  void Start() {
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().ResetCenterOfMass();
  }
}
```

this *does* cause the centre of mass to be recalculated correctly. However, the spawned object appears to have already been through at least one physics update with the wrong COM by this time, and so has already acquired some unexpected momentum.

Why isn't the COM being automatically recalculated, without me having to call `ResetCenterOfMass()` explicitly? And if I must trigger it manually, can I do that immediately after the calls to `Instantiate()` and `Scale()`, rather than deferring like this?

Comment: Hm, I'd thought the center of mass was stored in local coordinates and wouldn't be affected by uniform scaling. But the intertia tensor may change. Have you tried this with a call to [Physics.SyncTransfotms](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SyncTransforms.html) to push your scale changes to the physics engine immediately after scaling?

Comment: @DMGregory According to [Rigidbody.centerOfMass](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-centerOfMass.html) the center of mass "will not reflect the transform's scale". I guess that's saying that the center of mass coordinates are not _true_ local coordinates, due to the treatment of scale. Regardless, I can definitely see that applying a uniform scale to the transform requires that the COM vector is scaled identically (unless it happens to be at [0,0,0]), but that's not happening automatically. Unfortunately, Physics.SyncTransforms is having no effect, but thank you for the idea.

Comment: @DMGregory Apologies: Physics.SyncTransforms _is_ working. I don't know what I was doing wrong before. Thank you again!

Comment: Cool! I'd never used that method before. Want to write up an answer based on your experience with it?

Comment: Yep, I'll post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With thanks to @DMGregory for the suggestion, a call to [`Physics.SyncTransforms`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SyncTransforms.html) before invoking `Rigidbody.ResetCenterOfMass` fixes the problem:

```
public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour {

  public Transform SpawnPrefab;
  public Vector3 Scale;

    void Start () {
      var spawn = Instantiate(SpawnPrefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
      spawn.localScale = Vector3.Scale(spawn.localScale, Scale);
      Physics.SyncTransforms();
      spawn.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().ResetCenterOfMass();
    }
}
```

Evidently this direct modification of the transform scale isn't being automatically passed through to the physics engine, but `Physics.SyncTransforms` lets us manually flush those changes down to PhysX, so that the `ResetCenterOfMass` computation is then based on the correctly scaled transform.